# Want to print one statename only once

Tags: php, json

### My PHP code

```
<?php

    $url = 'https://data.gov.in/api/datastore/resource.json?resource_id=7eca2fa3-d6f5-444e-b3d6-faa441e35294&api-key=ac232a3b2845bbd5be2fc43a2ed8c625&filters[StateName]=MAHARASHTRA&sort[StateName]=asc&limit=5';

    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    foreach($json['records'] as $item) {

        print $item['StateName'];

        print '<br>';
    }
```

### My output

```
MAHARASHTRA 
MAHARASHTRA
MAHARASHTRA
MAHARASHTRA
MAHARASHTRA
```

### Expected output

```
MAHARASHTRA
```

I want to print one state name print only once. How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't YELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want state names (which your question indicates that you do), you can greatly simplify this as follows:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

$stateNames = array_unique(array_column($json['records'],"StateName"));
echo implode("<br>",$stateNames)."<br>";
```

`array_column` will return the "StateName" entry for each array entry and `array_unique` will remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$temp = array();
foreach($json['records'] as $item) {
    if(!in_array($item['StateName'],$temp)) {
         print $item['StateName']; 
         print '<br>';
    }
    $temp = $item['StateName'];
}
```